# install python/pip - python3.6 installed but scripts folder is empty, running get-pip.py requires pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Downloaded `python-3.6.7-amd64.exe` from official site and installed, but cannot find pip.

`scripts` folder under python installation is empty:

[image]

Trying to install `pip` with `get-pip.py` but got following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ and follow the steps.

Alternatively you can install python from the official website : https://www.python.org/
which will have 'pip' included.

Comment: did you do curl first

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking for a python update, it might realize it is missing and download it.